# PySpark recursive key search

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a deeply nested json esque structure that I need to search for a given key at all levels (up to 7) for all occurrences. There is data always present in level 0 that I need to associate with each occurrence of the `search_key` found at any level. I've tried pushing this data through the recursive calls and appending it on return, but I have ran into heap and unhashable type issues when I move this from standard Python to a PySpark RDD.

My search function is below:

```
def search(input, search_key, results):

    if input:
        for i in input:
            if isinstance(i, list):
                search(i, search_key, results)

            elif isinstance(i, dict):
                for k, v in i.iteritems():
                    if k == search_key:
                        results.append(i)
                        continue
                    elif isinstance(v, list):
                        search(v, search_key, results)
                    elif isinstance(v, dict):
                        search(v, search_key, results)

        return results
```

And I have been calling it with:

```
origin_rdd = sc.parallelize(origin)
concept_lambda = lambda c: search(c, term, [])
results = origin_rdd.flatMap(concept_lambda)
```

Can anybody suggest a way to capture the top level data and have it as part of each object in results? Results could be 0 to n so a product of 7 keys always present in the top level and then all occurrences of the search term collection. I then want to transform each row in the resulting RDD into a PySpark Row for use with a PySpark DataFrame. I have not found a good way to start with a DataFrame instead of an RDD or apply the search function to a DataFrame column because the structure is highly dynamic in its schema, but happy to hear suggestions if somebody thinks that's a better route.

Comment: If you know you only have up to 7 levels, why not try an iterative solution instead of recursive? Also, a [mcve] with some small sample data and the desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @pault I'll work on getting the example. And I started with a set that was only 3 levels, and since it has bounced around from 2 to 7 levels nested. I'm unfortunately not generating the input data that needs to be parsed or in a position to better define the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by slicing and passing the base through while using deepcopy when I had a hit on my search. Somebody else trying to do something similar could tweak the slices below.

```
origin_rdd = sc.parallelize(origin)
concept_lambda = lambda r: search(r[-1], r[0:9], term, [])
results = origin_rdd.flatMap(concept_lambda)
```

The search function

```
def search(input, row_base, search_key, results):    
    if input:
        for i in input:
            if isinstance(i, list):
                search(i, row_base, search_key, results)
            if isinstance(i, dict):
                for k, v in iteritems(i):
                    if k == search_key:
                        row = copy.deepcopy(row_base)
                        row.append(i)
                        results.append(row)
                        continue
                    elif isinstance(v, list):
                        search(v, row_base, search_key, results)
                    elif isinstance(v, dict):
                        search(v, row_base, search_key, results)

    return results
```